# is there any way to print title of dictionary which is in a list?

Tags: python

i want to print pets name(like sparky, draggy, thunder)

within the `for loop`. but i can not find the way to do it.

```
sparky = {
    'kind': 'dog',
    'owner': 'oh',
}

draggy = {
    'kind': 'dragon',
    'owner': 'harry',
}

thunder = {
    'kind': 'lightning',
    'owner': 'thor',
}

pets = [sparky, draggy, thunder]

for pet in pets:

    print(pet)
```

i tried print(pet.keys()), print(pet.values()) but nothing is successful.

Comment: Why don't you wrap all these individual dictionaries just lying around into a single bigger dictionary instead?  You don't realise it yet, but what you're asking is basically the ability to print a variable's name. I will unwillingly let you know it is possible, but you should NEVER EVER have to do it. It is ugly, and involves hacks essentially.

Comment: thank you for your comment. but is there a way???

Comment: No worries, check out Daniel's answer, it essentially shows a good way to do it.

Comment: wow! thank you Daniel's answer helps me.

Answer (score 4):

With your current setup is not possible, is better if you store those dictionaries in a dictionary or a list. For example, a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
pets = {'sparky': {
    'kind': 'dog',
    'owner': 'oh',
}, 'draggy': {
    'kind': 'dragon',
    'owner': 'harry',
}, 'thunder': {
    'kind': 'lightning',
    'owner': 'thor',
}}

for pet in pets:
    print(pet)
```

**Output**

```
thunder
sparky
draggy
```

Comment: You can show your appreciation for good answers by marking them as "accepted", which helps both you and your answerer out with some rep. @fianElf